# Can i crop .dcm images and then use them im .bmp format for my research work?

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

I have database of low-dose CT images that i have downloaded from [this link](https://eddie.via.cornell.edu/crpf.html), these images are in the format of **.dcm**, and i am not getting any way to read these image using BurreredImage, so what i have thought is to open these image using any editor and then crop these images and save them into **.bmp** format for further processing. Would it be correct as per **research** purpose.

Comment: If it's research, and you have permission to use the original data, almost anything goes. Not really sure what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Roger is correct. Most licenses don't apply for research. That link is from an educational institution so almost definitely OK to use for research.

Comment: I just want to know that will it make any difference in terms of intensity at any pixels. because i am changing images from .dcm to .bmp

Comment: Every time u convert an image u will lose some sort of quality. Best thing to do is to try it out